# Boundary conditions for Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: boundary-conditions, navier-stokes

The Navier-Stokes equations in combination with the continuity equation for incompressible Newtonian fluids is stated as

$$\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}+\left(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla\right)\mathbf{u}=-\frac 1\rho\nabla p+\nu\Delta\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{g}$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0.$$

The unknown dependent variables are velocity field $\mathbf{u}$ and the pressure $p$.

Normally, when solving a differential equation we have to specify some conditions for the dependent variables.

I don't quite understand why it is not necessary to specify the boundary condition for the pressure $p$, which is obviously a dependent variable, for this system of partial differential equations.

Comment: At what type of boundary? And why do you think you don't have to specify it?

Comment: For example the pipe flow. Most times in computational fluid dynamics software they only define velicities at the inlet, zero-gradient velocities at outlet and no-slip and no-through at the walls. Why is it not necessary to give pressure at least at one boundary?

Comment: Unless it is strictly a moving boundary problem, p (or total normal stress) must be specified at an inlet boundary, an outlet boundary, or both.  For example, in laminar flow in a pipe, if you don't specify the volumetric flow rate, you need to specify the pressure difference between inlet and outlet.  Note, that for the incompressible version of the flow equations that you have written, the pressure p is determined only up to an arbitrary constant (except if specified at one location).